# SSL ломает .php скрипты

Tags: php, ssl, https

Здравствйте все, кто будет читать эту тему. Возникла такая проблема: у меня два .php скрипта, один из них возвращает .png `(Content-type image/png)`, другой делает `imagecreatefrompng({обращение к первому})` и вырезает кусок (не суть важно, я думаю). Если я использую **http** при обращении к первому, то всё работает как должно. Если же я использую **https**, то результат работы - черная картинка. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В логе ошибок php наверняка написано, в чём проблема

Comment: мож редиректы неправильно настроены, загружайте созданное фото локально от корня диска, а не про протоколу http/https.

Comment: @Jean-Claude логично было бы предположить, что скрипты на разных серверах/сайтах